# Copy specific columns into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 2 sheets, I am only concerned with Sheet1 for this function.

I copy the data from columns A and G into a new workbook using the following code I found on this site.

```
Sub dural()
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Sheets(1).Select
Set r1 = Range("A:A")
Set r2 = Range("G:G")
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
r2.Copy Range("A1")
r1.Copy Range("B1")
End Sub
```

I don't need the new workbook to open and be displayed like the above code does.

I would like to automatically create and save the output as a new file, preferably in a specific directory. Lets call it output.xlsx. The original file is SOURCE.xlsm

Comment: `successfully using the following code I found on this site` this site also has what you want to do ~_^

Comment: I've been actively searching!  Not finding exactly what I'm looking for yet, maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: `wb.saveas filename:=`

Comment: Here's a *super* simple example of how to copy columns A-G from a workbook called "Original" to a workbook that you declared as `wbNew`: ("Sheet1") on both: `Workbooks("Original").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:G").Copy wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:G")`.

Comment: Batman, not what OP is asking _now_ but yes, that will come in handy later ~_^

Comment: You are specifying a range, I only need 2 columns

Comment: @JamesPage a column _is_ a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this:

```
Sub dural()
  With Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G:G").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Copy .Sheets(1).Range("B1")
    .SaveAs "your path + filename here"
    .Close
  End With
End Sub
```

should do all you want.

If you still have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: That worked beautifully, I salute you!

If the column contained formulas, is it possible to paste them as values?  I haven't searched yet, just came to me as I'm typing this

Comment: you could do it by splitting upt the copy-paste again and then using `.PasteSpecial 12` or something like that... check [this link for `.PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)